# how to apply photoshop effects on server

Tags: php, server, photoshop, effect

I need to apply text effects on the server. For example, I need to get an input image from the user and post to the server and apply photoshop text effects on it and return to user. How can I apply photoshop effects on server? Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: If you create all the letters beforehand and then serve them up matching what the user's text was.

Comment: but sometimes letters are hard to connect together! like 'g' and 'n' in above image.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Various [Image Processing and Generation functions provided by PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) ImageMagick & GD.

Consider [Gimp command line](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). you can easily done this from php using *exec()* function. GIMP is full of featured & can do almost all Photoshop actions. Its free!

I haven not done this before, but [Adobe Photoshop Scripting documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) you should have to try this but for this your language must be JavaScript and VBScript.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**

> You Can Get CSS From PhotoShop For Corresponding Objects

**

But Photoshop CS5 Or Up Only Support This

You Can Get Properties Like Gradient And Many Things From Photoshop

Simply Select The Layer you Want To GEt The Effect
Go to Layer Menu-->copy css

This Will Copy THe CsS of correspondant Layer

Comment: but how apply it to a text??

Comment: use a text type tool and copy the css